# Taking forever to run

Tags: java, performance, runtime

I am working on a project for class and we are to take code we leanred from the book to put together a circular queue (called ring buffer in this project) and after hours of reading/fixing errors and putting all together I ended up with this:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class RingBuffer<Item> implements Iterable<Item>
{
private int maxSize,size,first,last;
private Item[] buffer;

public RingBuffer(int maxSize)
{
    this.maxSize=maxSize;
    buffer=(Item[])new Object[maxSize];
}

public boolean isEmpty(){return size==0;}

public boolean isFull(){return size==maxSize;}

public void enqueue(Item item)
{
    if(isFull())
        throw new RuntimeException("The buffer is full");
    buffer[last]=item;
    last++;
    if(last==maxSize)
        last=0;
    size++;
}

public Item dequeue()
{
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new RuntimeException("The buffer is empty");
    Item item=buffer[first];
    first++;
    if(first==maxSize)
        first=0;
    size--;
    return item;
}

public Iterator<Item> iterator()
{
    return new RingBufferIterator();
}

public class RingBufferIterator implements Iterator<Item>
{
    private int current;
    private boolean iterated;
    public RingBufferIterator()
    {
        current=first;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        if(iterated)
            return current!=last;
        return true;
    }

    public Item next()
    {
        if(!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Item result=buffer[current];
        current++;
        if(current==maxSize)
            current=0;
        iterated=true;
        return result;
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input=new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
    PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out),true);

    RingBuffer<String> ring=new RingBuffer<String>(5);

    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        String item=input.next();
        if(!item.equals("-"))
            ring.enqueue(item);
        else if(!ring.isEmpty())
            output.print(ring.dequeue()+" ");
    }
    output.println();
    for(String st:ring)
        output.print(st+" ");

    output.println();
}
}
```

No errors but we are given the args to run for the assignment, which I added in the run settings for netbeans. I pressed run about a half hour ago and it is still running. I've never encountered this problem as a cs student before and was wondering what could cause this. Is there anything needed to be changed in the coding or can some code take this long to run and I should wait it out? Thanks in advance

Comment: with the aid of the debugger you should spot the bug quite easily... it's almost impossible to write down a piece of code and make it run smoothly and error-free on the very first try :-)

Comment: Hi @G_G, thanks for the quick response. I ran this on both netbeans and eclipse and it didn't come up with any errors(it did before and I fixed them). Since you say there is an easy bug problem it will keep bothering me until I find it I guess lol

Comment: Your problem is called "infinite loop". It could also be "infinite blocking". Both can be easily discovered with a profiling tool like VisualVM (comes with netbeans).

Comment: If you use the **debugger** in either NetBeans or Eclipse it will tell you exactly what the issue is. You could also use something like JVisualVM to monitor the application. Or, in the worst case, you can use `kill -3` to get thread dump. There is no error, because the code is perfectly valid - there are many reasons you might actually _want_ an infinite loop.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik @ BoristheSpider Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't even think of doing that. I am running the debugger now and its taking it's time also (is that normal for the debugger to take a bit of time too?)

Comment: No errors at compile time doesnt necessarly means no errors at runtime. These are two completely different things. In fact, you can always create a perfecly valid program that do thre wrong thing eheheh. A good profiler-debugger should do the trick.

Comment: @G_G I am leaving it to debug for now since that seems to be taking its time too and I'll see what it says after that. Thanks for all of the help with this!

Comment: The debugger _plugs into_ the running application. You need to look at, for example, the running threads and their stacktraces to see what they are doing. A debugger doesn't _fix_ anything - you need to do that - it's just a tool. I would start by [reading the documentation](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider ok thank you. I will try that out tomorrow then as it it 6:30 am where I am and can't bring myself to work on this any longer for the night. Thanks again

Comment: Hey, I tried using the debugger on netbeans and on eclipse and I still can't figure out how to change it. So I'm going to either try redoing it another way completely or just take the hit on this assignment for the semester. Just wanted to thank you guys for the input @BoristheSpider @ G_G @ MarkoTopolnik